# use wp_get_attachment_image() to show attachments

Tags: attachments, images

I really hope this is a facepalm moment, b/c i'm getting frustrated with this.  Making a quick loop to show certain attachment images.  lifted it almost straight from the codex but wp_get_attachment_image() isn't behaving like I'd expect.

isn't the ID part of the wp_get_attachment_image the ID of the attachment?  is that not the same as the post id of the attachment?

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => array('image','image/jpeg','image/png','image/gif'),
        'numberposts' => 5,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'post_title'
    );


$attachments = get_posts( $args );
     if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
           echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' , true);
           echo '<p>' . $attachment->post_title . '</p>';
          }
     }
```

prints out the post titles but no images.

**EDIT 1:** yes I am definitely getting posts with my get_posts

some more debugging:

```
$attachments = get_posts( $args );
     if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
           $image= wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' , false, array( 'id' => $attachment->ID ));
           echo $image;
           print_r(wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' , false, array( 'id' => $attachment->ID )));
           echo var_export($image);
           echo '<p>' . $attachment->post_title . '</p>';
          }
     }
}
```

returns this:

```
Array ( [0] => http://localhost/multi/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/FabricColllFabrics-150x150.jpg [1] => 100 [2] => 100 [3] => 1 ) 
false
FabricColllFabrics
```

for the first image... so wp_get_attachment_image_src is correctly finding the source, but wp_get_attachment_image is apparently returning false?

**edit 2:** and there's the face palm i was waiting on

at some point i must've been debugging something and for who knows what reason i put a

```
function wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, $size='thumbnail', $icon = false) {
  return false;
```

right at the beginning of wp_get_attachment_image

this is all localhost stuff, and i don't usually hack at core, but i guess at some point i was in there probably trying to backtrace something and forgot to clean up after myself.  epic fail.

Comment: What do you get if you just use `wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID )`?

Comment: You should add your "solution" as answer, so you mark it later on and not leave it open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solution:** the the face palm i was waiting on

at some point i must've been debugging something and for who knows what reason i put a

```
function wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, $size='thumbnail', $icon = false) {
  return false;
```

right at the beginning of wp_get_attachment_image

this is all localhost stuff, and i don't usually hack at core, but i guess at some point i was in there probably trying to backtrace something and forgot to clean up after myself. epic fail.

Answer (score 2):

You're obviously getting data returned for `$attachments = get_posts()`; otherwise, you wouldn't be able to output `$attachment->post_title`. So the issue *must* be with your `wp_get_attachment_image()` call.

The first thing I would check is: why are you setting the `$icon` parameter to `true`? This parameter is intended to output a mime-type icon, instead of the actual attachment image. Try setting it to `false` (or omitting the parameter altogether, since `false` is the default).

Other than that, it's a long-shot, but try omitting `full`, and let `wp_get_attachment_image()` attempt to output its default image size, `thumbnail`.

Comment: yes i was getting data returned for $attachments.  thank you so much for your response. while the problem ended up being my own stupidity (like i thought it was) you and @kaiser both helped me finally find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem debugging:

If you `var_export()` the result of `$image = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' , true);` and get `string(0)`, then it's simply skipping, as the image wasn't received.

#### Debuggin deeper:

Just add the 4th argument as array to `wp_get_attachment_image()`: `array( 'id' => $attachment->ID )`; and then try the following in your functions.php file:

```
function debug_img_atts( $attr, $attachment )
{
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump( $attr );
    var_dump( $attachment );
    echo '<pre>';
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'debug_img_atts', 20, 2 );
```

and see if your id is the one from your attachments.

Another problem could be that your image size isn't registered. The default image size is 'thumbnail'. Try to leave the 3rd arg empty and then use `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );` to your functions.php and see if you get an output.

You could also try to use `var_dump( wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID ) );`

A last solution would be to simply leave the `post_mime_type` parameter out and check what MIME type the actual attachment is, before dropping it back into your query. Use [`var_dump( get_post_mime_type( $attachment->ID ) );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_mime_type) to inspect it

Comment: thank you so much for your very detailed response.  you definitely helped me find the offending piece of code